# Look for overlapping values in 2 dimensional array and remove one based on x criteria

Tags: c#, arrays, algorithm

Assuming I have the following 2 dimensional array:

```
{{0,1,2,3,4}, {6,7,8,9}, {5,6}, {10}}
```

How can I find the overlapping indices? (Notice the 6 overlap) And remove one based on x criteria?

The output should be

```
{{0,1,2,3,4}, {6,7,8,9}, {10}, {5}}
```

or

```
{{0,1,2,3,4}, {7,8,9}, {5,6}, {10}}
```

based on x. x is an int value. 0 should output with no change, 1 should output the top, 2 should output the bottom.

I am 100% sure that all of the sub arrays are sequences from n to k incrementing by one.

Comment: Are you 100% sure that all of the sub arrays are sequences from n to k incrementing by one, or do they need to be validated first?  What do you want the output to be?  Just `6` (i.e. all of the values seen more than once)?  Or do you want collections of arrays that have overlapping values?

Comment: The output should be

this: {{0,1,2,3,4}, {6,7,8,9}, {10}, {5}}

or

this: {{0,1,2,3,4}, {7,8,9}, {5,6}, {10}}

based on x.

Comment: What should the output of `{{1,2,3},{2}}` be?  Or is that not a case that can happen?

Comment: It will never have that situation. The values that overlap will always be on the sides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just keep track of all of the items you've used so far in a set, and then for each new inner array you can just yield all of the items except those already used:

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<int>> Foo(int[][] data)
{
    var items = new HashSet<int>();
    foreach (var array in data)
    {
        yield return array.Except(items);
        items.UnionWith(array);
    }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't there be an if statement for x? Could you show me usage?

Comment: @rotaercz I have no idea what you mean by that.  What is the criteria?  This method takes the input your provided and produces one of the outputs you stated is valid.

Comment: I've added more additional explanation in the question. Sorry for not being more clear.

Comment: @rotaercz All you need to do is reverse the order of the arrays to flip between the two outputs.  I don't even think it's worth adding to this method. Just call `.Reverse` on the array before passing it in (and reverse the output again if that's important to you) and voila.

Comment: Oh gotcha. How do you see the values? I'm trying this:
var a = Extension.CheckOverlaps(filtered).ToArray();
Debug.Log(string.Join(",", a.Select(x => x.ToString()).ToArray()));
And I'm getting: System.Linq.Enumerable+<CreateExceptIterator>c__Iterator4`1[System.Int32],System.Linq.Enumerable+<CreateExceptIterator>c__Iterator4`1[System.Int32],System.Linq.Enumerable+<CreateExceptIterator>c__Iterator4`1[System.Int32],System.Linq.Enumerable+<CreateExceptIterator>c__Iterator4`1[System.Int32]

Comment: @rotaercz It creates a sequence of sequences.  It's two dimentional.  You need to iterate the outer sequences and then iterate the inner sequences and print out the string value of the items in the inner sequence.  The `ToString` of the sequence itself isn't particularly helpful, as you've seen.  You'd essentially print it just like you would a 2d array; two nested for loops.

Comment: I'm getting a Cannot convert System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<int> to int

Comment: My brain must have been broken or something. Figured it out. :)

Answer (score 0):

A non-C#-specific answer:

- Sort the arrays by their smallest value
- Iterate through the arrays

  - If the greatest element of the current array is smaller than the smallest element of the next array, we don't have an overlap, so do nothing
  - If you want to remove elements from the current array, cut off from the element that is equal to the smallest value of the next array.
  - If you want to remove elements from the next array, cut off to the element that is equal to the greatest value of the current array.

Since these are arrays and the sequential elements are incremented by one, we can determine the cut index by doing a simple subtraction, we don't need to step through the array.

This will remove the ordering of the arrays, but, from the example, that doesn't appear to be important.
If it is important, it is not difficult to keep the original index of each array.

If one array can overlap with multiple other arrays (on the same side), there may be some additional complexity, but it shouldn't be too difficult to deal with.

**Example:**

```
Input: {{0,1,2,3,4}, {6,7,8,9}, {5,6,7}, {10}}  
Sorted: {{0,1,2,3,4}, {5,6,7}, {6,7,8,9}, {10}}

Arrays 1 and 2:  
4 < 5, no overlap

Arrays 2 and 3:  
7 >= 6, overlap  
Either cut off 6 and 7 from array 2, or 6 and 7 from array 3  
(depending on what output you want)

Arrays 3 and 4:
9 < 10, no overlap

Output:  
{{0,1,2,3,4}, {5}, {6,7,8,9}, {10}}  
or  
{{0,1,2,3,4}, {5,6,7}, {8,9}, {10}}
```